# Why is htmlspecialchars adding slashes to my webpage?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, htmlspecialchars

I have my input placed into mySQL through a PDO prepared statement, and have it placed in my website with PHP using htmlspecialchars() to protect against XSS. Only problem is **now I get slashes, before any quotes, that are visible on the webpage to the user** it only happens when I upload it to the server. Never happens on my localhost.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server has magic quotes enabled?

Try this line in PHP to find out:

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    echo "Magic quotes are enabled";
else
    echo "Magic quotes are disabled";
```

If they are enabled, you can use `stripslashes` to remove them.

Comment: Checked, Magic quotes are disabled

Comment: Are you sure it is htmlspecialchars? Have you checked the output prior (or without) that function call? It could be being caused by some SQL escaping

Comment: Don't use any SQL escaping. Everything is put in the database through PDO so I don't have to

Comment: Crap, you're right. Checked my db and it's in there with the slashes. How the heck did that happen :-/

Comment: Wow, thank you for this post. You ended my hours of hair pulling.  No wonder they deprecated this horrible feature.  http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.whynot.php